# How do I get an int

Tags: sql, math

Seems like a simple question... but I am stumped.

```
    declare @Total_User int
    set @Total_User = 8

    declare @Total int
    set @Total = 12

    declare @Number int
    set @Number = (@Total_User / @Total) * 100
    select @Number as 'Standard'
```

I am expecting 66, but my select comes out zero ??

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `(@Total_User / @Total)` is zero, as it is doing integer division.

You can multiply by 100 first, which gives the result that you expected:

```
set @Number = 100 * @Total_User / @Total
```

To get a rounded value rather than truncated, you would use floating point values and the `round` function:

```
set @Number = round(100.0 * @Total_User / @Total, 0)
```

This will give the result `67` rather than `66`, as that is closer to the actual result `66.6666666666`

Answer (score 1):

Try:
set @Number = (@Total_User*100 / @Total)

Comment: This will cause rounding errors. Bath's solution is better

Comment: ...although in this case the rounding errors aren't apparent.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: When will there be a difference?

Comment: @Guffa: in this case, never. But I was thinking down the road when the asker decides he wants more precision, so he simply makes `Number` a float. The answer @Bathsheba submitted will survive that but this one won't.

Comment: @Guffa: Others have provided survivable solutions as well at this point, but Bath was first.

Comment: @Guffa: You're right, though. I should have made that more clear in my initial comments. My comments were **not** intended to be an indictment of this solution (which 100% correct AND was the first answer overall), but rather an acknowledgment that Bath's is more flexible and therefore more future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your division `@Total_User / @Total` is using **integer arithmetic** *i.e.* any remainder will be discarded, so that part of the expression will be 0.

To fix, write `(1.0 * @Total_User / @Total) * 100`. This promotes the operation to floating point.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer arithmetic, that is why you see the `0`, make at least one of the operand as `float` and you will see the correct result like:

```
declare @Total float
```

Or you can cast one operand as `float` like:

```
et @Number = (CAST(@Total_User as float) / @Total) * 100
```

Your current code is doing:

```
8 / 12
```

Which would result in `0.666666666667`, but since both of your operands are of type `int` the calculation is performed using `int` type, thus result in `0` and not `0.66666666667`.

Answer (score 0):

You get 0 because you are doing integer division of @Total_User and @Total.

You have two options to get the correct result:

1. First multiply Ttotal_User by 100 and then divide by @Total:

   ```
   set @Number = (@Total_User * 100) / @Total
   ```
2. Cast @Total_User and @Total to floating point before making the division:

   ```
   set @Number = (cast(@Total_User as float) / cast(@Total as float)) * 100
   ```

Answer (score 0):

declare @Total_User float, 
           @Total float, 
           @Number float

```
SET @Total_User = 8
SET @Total = 12

SET @Number = @Total_User / @Total * 100

select CAST(@Number AS INT) AS 'Standard'
```

This will give you 66